# ASP.NET web app throwing exception when trying to access MySQL database with user other than root

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to avoid using my root user as the user that accesses my MySQL database in my ASP.NET web app.  Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=90.232.111.231;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=root;Password=rootpassword;Convert Zero Datetime=True"/>
```

The application works with no issue with that connection string.  However, when I change the connection string to this:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=90.232.111.231;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Convert Zero Datetime=True"/>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Parameter 'eturnValue' not found in the collection.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter 'eturnValue' not found in the collection.
```

This comes during the log in at the first attempt to access the database.

I have no idea where eturnValue is coming from, as the only difference between the runs is which user I am try to access the database with.  I confirmed that my mysql user has been set up correctly, it has all the privileges the root account does, at least that is what I was told by my host's support.

I am calling a stored procedure through the MySql objects in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Something is trying to iterate through the items in a collection (presumably it would be looking for 'ReturnValue'), but somewhere it has been typed as 'eturnValue', and so cannot find it.

As I can't tell from your exception detail where it came from, you should perform a 'Find in Files' for 'eturnValue' - you may find that there is a typo in your code. Or check the Stored Procedures in the database for the same.

Comment: If there was a typo in the code, the root user would run into the same problem.

Comment: You are probably right there Jack, I was just covering any possibilities of what the app is doing and when the error is occurring. It could be happening after connection, and app code then navigating to the home or login page, where the called stored procedure may be different in the database according to the connection properties. Not a likely scenario, but if looking for the typo, may as look everywhere you can just in case.

Comment: Steve, no worries.  I appreciate the input.  This issue is a brain burner.